# Vim Ultisnips - How do I move to the next placeholder or tabstop?

Tags: vim, placeholder, macvim, tabstop, ultisnips

I just installed a brand new copy of Macvim and [UltiSnips](https://gitcafe.com/doun/utilsnips), but I can't figure out how to move to the next completions using tabstops and placeholders.

When I press tab, it simply adds a tab space.

My guess is that the tab key was remapped in another plugin or vimrc, so I went with fresh installs and an empty ~/.vim folder.  Still nothing...

How do I move to the next tabstop?  Is there a key mapping I can set?

Comment: [This is UltiSnips real home.](https://launchpad.net/ultisnips) Use it to ask questions to the author.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I have the following in my `vimrc`:

```
" Set ultisnips triggers
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"                                            
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<tab>"                                       
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<s-tab>"
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me :( although I can move with ctrl+j

Answer (score 6):

It looks like jumping to the next tabstop was mapped to control j.  I switched it to tab in the ultisnips source.

```
" The trigger used to jump forward to the next placeholder.
" NOTE: expansion and forward jumping can, but needn't be the same trigger

if !exists("g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger")
    let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger = "<tab>"
endif
```

Comment: can i make a similar change to `JumpBackwardTrigger` using `backspace` key.. and if yes, what should i place inside `"<   >"`

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked only after saving and sourcing my `init.vim`, doing a `:PlugInstall`, and then reopening `nvim`..